# Ajax Single Field Submission in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've created an order form, of which has a large array of fields. I'm now adding coupon functionality so that we can start to give customers discount codes etc.

What's the best way of submitting a single field (the coupon code) using ajax after a "apply coupon" button has been clicked so that the price can be updated on the front end probably using UJS(?) - obviously the final price calculation would happen on the backend?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a JS framework to do Ajax requests. If you JQuery, then you can use the example given to understand how to do a [simple post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="/" id="searchForm">
   <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search..." />
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form>
  <!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
  <div id="result"></div>

<script>
  /* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault(); 

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( 'action' );

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.post( url, { s: term },
      function( data ) {
          var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
          $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
      }
    );
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there no link_to (with post params) equivalent in Rails?